# How to increment Methods within a Class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I would like to increment methods within a python class but I don't know how to do it. Code will be easier to understand than words so here it is...

I do this because I want to use the methods later. I've tried first to create an incremental list of functions that I could use later, but it doesn't work. this is why I'm trying to do it this way.

**What I would like as a result -> Works:**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def method_1(self):
        print(self.value * 1)

    def method_2(self):
        print(self.value * 2)

    def method_3(self):
        print(self.value * 3)

    def method_4(self):
        print(self.value * 4)

mc = MyClass(5)
mc.method_1()
mc.method_2()
mc.method_3()
mc.method_4()
```

**What I would like as a way to write it -> Doesn't work:**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.value = val

    for i in range(0,5):
        def method_i(self):
            print(self.value * (i + 1))

mc = MyClass(5)
mc.method_1()
mc.method_2()
mc.method_3()
mc.method_4()
```

Comment: why not just `def method(self, i): return self.value * i`? I can't think of a way to do that, but even if there was, this is not a good idea in general as it makes the code hard to debug and follow

Comment: Thank you for your answers,

@Tomerikoo i'm not doing this because what I show you is very simplified, In reality I want to use the methods later.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not advisable:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

for i in range(5):
    def method_xxx(self, i=i):  # avoid late binding problem
        print(self.value * (i + 1))
    # Correct names:
    method_xxx.__name__ = method_xxx.__name__.replace("xxx", str(i + 1))
    method_xxx.__qualname__ = method_xxx.__qualname__.replace("xxx", str(i + 1))
    # bind to class:
    setattr(MyClass, "method_{}".format(i + 1), method_i)
```

Because interpolation is not really possible, we need to define the method under a different name first (if we want to avoid `eval` & Co.). Definition outside the class itself is necessary because the class body is executed before the class is created, so its name is not available yet.

---

Instead, it's a much better idea to just give the number as an argument to a more general method:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    def method(self, i):
        print(self.value + i)
```

Comment: Looks great ! it works, now i'm going to try to implement it in my more complicated code... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should not. It is not advisable to use variable numbering instead of, say, lists.

If the methods are indeed all doing the same thing up to a parameter, you probably want to make this a single method.

```
class MyClass:
    ...

    def method(self, i):
        print(self.value * i)
```

If the method have a no recognizable pattern, then you will need to define them anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in reality I need these to be in 2 different methods because i'm using threads for live plotting in Qt, and each thread need its own method or function. This is why I can't use a general method

Comment: I don't really know, I've guessed it because when I'm trying using only one function (with different arguments) my GUI only take the last commandement into account. While when I'm doing the same thing by creating 2 different function, it works. (I'm talking about 2 but in reality it's from 2 to 100+)

Comment: You should ask another question specifically about multi threading, not method names. Your function is probably stateful and/or you need a lock around it. In any case, your problem is not related to names, but to threading

Comment: Ok i'll have a look at multi threading and ask if I can't understand it by myself. I'm quite new at using this kind of tool... Thank you :)